# How to fill area under plot using a color map?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have one diagram showing a function f(x,y) like imshow does, and a second diagram that shows the probability distribution P(f). Find below an image of the situation. The code for the plot at the bottom is basically

```
\addplot[const plot,fill=black!20,very thin] file{hist.dat} \closedcycle;
```

To increase the visual connection between both images, I'd like to use the colormap from the first diagram in the second diagram: The currently gray area below the histogram plot should be filled with the colormap's gradient in x direction.

I tried to achieve that with stuff like `fill=mapped color` and different plot types like `ycomb` and `ybar interval`, but it seems that, out of the box, only `mesh` and `scatter` support colormaps, and both are unsuitable for my scenario.

[image: Here is an image of the situation.]

EDIT: For completeness, here is my solution, derived from the accepted answer.

```
\def\defcolormapshading#1#2{%
 \pgfplotscolormaptoshadingspec{#2}{50pt}\tempa%
 \def\tempb{\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{#1}{\paperheight}}%
 \expandafter\tempb\expandafter{\tempa}%
 \let\tempa\undefined\let\tempb\undefined%
}%
```

Put this in your preamble. Then, before the tikzpicture environment, say

```
\defcolormapshading{myshading}{mymap}
```

(replace "mymap" by the colormap name, and "myshading" by a descriptive name for the shading). Then give the key `shading=myshading` to `\addplot`. The use of `\pgfplotscolormaptoshadingspec` like in this snippet is detailed in the pgfplots manual.

Comment: I would like to use the `jet` colormap as defined in the pgfplots manual. Though any colormap that I tried (except for `hot` which is used in the example on p. 175) fails: "the colormap 'jet' is undefined! Maybe you misspelled it?". How did you get the rainbow out of it?

Comment: for some reason it is working, when I first do `\pgfplotsset{colormap#2}` and then `\pgfplotscolormaptoshadingspec{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/colormap name}}{50pt}\tempa`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could just define an appropriate shading using `\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading` and use that to fill your plot. The colour at position `25bp` of the shading is the leftmost visible color, that at `75bp` is the rightmost visible colour.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{stefan}{100bp}{
color(0bp)=(blue!50!black);
color(25bp)=(blue!50!black);
color(50bp)=(blue);
color(55bp)=(green);
color(60bp)=(yellow);
color(65bp)=(orange);
color(70bp)=(red);
color(75bp)=(red!50!black);
color(100bp)=(red!50!black)
}

\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,domain=-2.63:1.39,point meta=x]
\addplot [shading=stefan] coordinates {(-2.63,0.2) (-0.5,0.4) (-0.2,0.5) (-0.1,2.6) (0,0.8) (0.1,0.7) (0.2,0.8) (0.4,2.2) (0.5,0.4) (1.39,0.3)} \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. With the pointer to shadings, I found \pgfplotscolormaptoshadingspec which does the job for me. The only weird thing is that I have to hand-adjust the second parameter to that command, it seems to depend on the plot width.

Comment: Yeah, I played around with that command first, too, but found that using `\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading` directly (`\pgfplotscolormaptoshadingspec` is just a wrapper for this function) is less comfortable in case you need fine control over the the shading, since the `pgfplots` color maps need to be specified in uniform steps.