# Tikz: Coloring area of stack plot using point meta

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to color the area between stack plots in tikz using explicitly given point meta.

My code, for now, is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
xlabel={x},
ylabel={y},
stack plots=y,
area style,
]

\addplot+[point meta=explicit]
table[mark=none,col sep=space]
{
0 5. 9
5 4. 8
10 3. 7
20 2. 5
}
\closedcycle;

\addplot+[point meta=explicit]
table[mark=none,col sep=space]
{
0 5. 1
5 6. 2
10 7. 3
20 8. 5
}
\closedcycle;


\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

This results in the following figure:

[image: Try]

What I desire is that the area is not shaded like it is now, but instead applies a shading similar to the one in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27861/242959).
It should, however, use the values given by the point meta and apply the coloring to both areas.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!